# populating from json with Angular1 (Using Angular Material)

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-material

I am able to do something similar everywhere else, but not with checkboxes. What am I missing here?

My json looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
     {
        "id": 1,
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ],
        ...a bunch of other stuff...
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3",
            "tag4"
        ],
        ...a bunch of other stuff...
    }
 ]
 }
```

And my HTML (Angular) looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in ::vm.media.tags track by $index">
     <md-checkbox >
         {{tag.tags}}
     </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

I am having a hard time getting the actual text or name of the tags to show next to the checkbox. ALl I am getting is the checkboxes alone as the image shows below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is working fine. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/YNMLjd

Comment: Not quite. Each tag is its own checkbook. That's why the ng repeat is different in my code than yours

Comment: you want checkbox for each tag in data ?

Comment: Correct :). There are several items and each has different tags and amount of tags. The ng repeat should display all tags for that particular item with a checbox

Comment: check the updated codepen

Comment: That looks like it might do the trick. I'll check it out later on. As long as it doesn't display every tag in the entire json but just the ones for the item that is being pulled. That's why I had the ng repeat written a little different but we'll see. Hopefully it will work :) thanks I'll update and credit the answer if correct.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything specific then I'll add the answer. :)

Comment: Perfect! Answer the question so I can credit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use one more `ng-repeat` to iterate all the tags for each data item.
Here is the code.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data.data" layout="column">
 <span> ID: {{data.id}}</span>
 <md-checkbox ng-repeat="eachTag in data.tags">
  {{eachTag}}
 </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

Here is the working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/next1/pen/YNMLjd).